# Issues with touchesBegan method

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch, sprite-kit, alpha

So the problem is that when I start it the soundOff button is above the soundOn but it's invisible. So all I see is the soundOn button, when I try to tap the soundOn button it really is just hitting the soundOff button and not giving it a chance to run the touchesBegan method properly.

```
@implementation GameScene
{
SKSpriteNode *soundLogo;
SKSpriteNode *soundOff;
}


-(void) addSoundOff:(CGSize)size {
soundOff = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"soundOff"];
//resize sprite
soundOff.size = CGSizeMake(soundOff.size.width/2.25, soundOff.size.height/2.25);
//position it
soundOff.position = CGPointMake(65, 25);
//name sound off
soundOff.name = @"soundOff";

soundOff.alpha = 0;
[self addChild:soundOff];

}

-(void) addSoundOn:(CGSize)size {
SKTexture *soundOn = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"soundLogo"];
soundLogo = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:soundOn];
//resize sprite
soundLogo.size = CGSizeMake(soundLogo.size.width/2.25, soundLogo.size.height/2.25);
//position sprite
CGPoint myPoint = CGPointMake(65, 25);
soundLogo.position = myPoint;
//name sound logo
soundLogo.name = @"soundOn";
//add action

[self addChild:soundLogo];
}

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

//sound logo pressed to turn sound on/off
if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"soundOn"]) {

    soundOff.alpha = 1;
    soundLogo.alpha = 0;

    NSLog(@"sound on is pressed");
}

if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"soundOff"]) {

    soundOff.alpha = 0;
    soundLogo.alpha = 1;
    NSLog(@"sound off is pressed");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather then changing the alpha to 0/1 what you can do is remove sprite from parent and you can add to child.

Don't add sound off and sound on button at same time first add the default button that is sound on.

now when the sound on button is clicked then remove the sound on button from parent and add sound off.

```
-(void) addSoundOff:(CGSize)size {
soundOff = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"soundOff"];
//resize sprite
soundOff.size = CGSizeMake(soundOff.size.width/2.25, soundOff.size.height/2.25);
//position it
soundOff.position = CGPointMake(65, 25);
//name sound off
soundOff.name = @"soundOff";

soundOff.alpha = 0;

//-------------Remove below line-----------------//
//[self addChild:soundOff]; 

//Dont add sound off button..... 
}

-(void) addSoundOn:(CGSize)size {
SKTexture *soundOn = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"soundLogo"];
soundLogo = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:soundOn];
//resize sprite
soundLogo.size = CGSizeMake(soundLogo.size.width/2.25, soundLogo.size.height/2.25);
//position sprite
CGPoint myPoint = CGPointMake(65, 25);
soundLogo.position = myPoint;
//name sound logo
soundLogo.name = @"soundOn";
//add action

[self addChild:soundLogo];
}

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

//sound logo pressed to turn sound on/off
if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"soundOn"]) {
    [soundLogo removeFromParent];
    [self addChild:soundOff];

    NSLog(@"sound on is pressed");
}

if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"soundOff"]) {

    [soundOff removeFromParent];
    [self addChild:soundLogo];
}
}
```

Comment: I know of the removeFromParent and the addChild but what would the code be for those inside the touchesBegan method?

Comment: I have the exact code for the removeFromParent and addChild and I got rid of the addChild in the soundOff method call. Now when I run and click it my game terminates with uncaught exception of type NSException. Not sure what's happening.

Comment: well pls debug the code and check what is exception and try to resolve it